# Navigate to app permission page in SAPUI5 + cordova mobile app

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, sapui5

I have created one application, where I want to navigate user to app permission page on click of button.

I have tried this plugin.
https://github.com/guyromb/Cordova-open-native-settings

While debugging the application, I am getting that above plugin is undefined.

```
jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.MessageBox");
                        sap.m.MessageBox.confirm("Please enable location permission.", function(evt){
                            if(evt=="OK"){
                                alert("good");
                                if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.settings) {
                                   console.log('openNativeSettingsTest is active');
                                   window.cordova.plugins.settings.open("wifi", function() {
                                           console.log('opened settings');
                                       },
                                       function () {
                                           console.log('failed to open settings');
                                       }
                                   );
                               } else {
                                   console.log('openNativeSettingsTest is not active!');
                               }
                               }
                               else{
                                alert("Cancelled!!");
                               return false;
                               }
                        });
```

In above code, while debugging at if condition, `window.cordova.plugins.settings` getting as `undefined`.

May I know the reason? Also is there any plugin available for SAPUI5 mobile app to open app setting page?

Thanks in advance.